# MySQL の index において、 null はどこに配置される？

Tags: mysql

innodb にて、 gap/next key lock が原因と思われる、他のトランザクションの commit 待ちを目撃しました。ふと、 MySQL/innodb のインデックスにおいて、 null はどこに配置されるのだろう、と思いました。

## 質問

- MySQL/innodb の index において、 null はどこに配置されますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `test2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `val_idx` (`val`)
);

INSERT INTO `test2` (`id`,`val`) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO `test2` (`id`,`val`) VALUES (2,NULL);
```

上記のようなテーブルを作成し、 `select * from test2 order by val` を実行したところ、

```
+----+------+
| id | val  |
+----+------+
|  2 | NULL |
|  1 |    2 |
+----+------+
```

となったので、

- `NULL` は、インデックス上すべての値の手前に挿入される

と理解しました。